# Extracting data from the 2nd table by looking at the condition in a table with php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my table named Follow, there is the information of those who are followed. For example, let's say my user id is 1:

```
tableID | followerID | followedID
___________________________________

1       | 1          | 13
2       | 1          | 32
```

In this table, I follow users with 13 and 32 user IDs.

I have a table named story. In this table, there are blog posts written by each user. Now I want to see the blogs of my users that I follow on the homepage.

```
storyID | userID | storyDesc
___________________________________

1       | 1      | Lorem Ipsum
2       | 13     | Dolor set
3       | 32     | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Normally I can do this as follows:

```
$connect=$db->preparea("SELECT * FROM story");
$connect->execute();
while($story = $connect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC){

    $con=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM follow where followerID='1' and 
    followedID='{$story['userID']}'");
    $con->execute();
    $count = $con->rowCount();

    if($count == 1){
        echo $story['storyDesc'];
    }
}
```

Can I do this directly from the sql query?

Comment: Learn about JOIN and COUNT in sql, these will help you towards your goal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right thing to do, but I tried something like this and it worked:

```
$connect=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM story RIGHT JOIN follow ON story.userID=follow.followedID where follow.followerID='{1}'");
$connect->execute();
while($result = $connect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $result['storyDesc'];
}
```

Thank you for helping:)